# Visual Studio: prevent collapsing folders in solution explorer when opened

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2022, codemaid

Every time I open a project in Visual Studio 2022 all folders in the solution explorer tree are collapsing. This is very annoying and interrupts my workflow. I couldn't find any setting for this. Is there a way to prevent this behavior?

This also appears to happen in older versions of Visual Studio.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Visual Studio 2022: prevent collapsing folders in solution explorer (2)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73023588/visual-studio-2022-prevent-collapsing-folders-in-solution-explorer-2)

Answer (score 14):

As @arkord commented on their own question, the auto-collapse is not coming from VS 2022, but rather from the **CodeMaid** extension. However they cited the incorrect settings.

1. In Visual Studio, from the menu bar, select "Extensions" - "CodeMaid" - "Options..."
2. Then select the "Collapsing" section
3. Uncheck both the options for:

   - *Collapse solutions when they are opened*
   - *If there is only one project in a solution, keep it expanded but still collapse its children*
4. Select the **Save** button

Now when opening your solutions in Visual Studio 2022, they should not auto-collapse, instead returning to where you last left off.