# Visual Studio 2022 is Auto-collapsing Solution Explorer Folder Trees

Tags: visual-studio-2022, solution-explorer

I've upgraded from VS 2019 to VS 2022. I have found that Visual Studio 2022 is automatically collapsing Solution Explorer sub-folders trees whilst I edit the code. I do not have the CodeMaid extension installed and I have ticked the checkbox "Track Active Items in Solution Explorer" in Tools->Projects and Solutions->General.

Any ideas as to what I should do to keep these sub-folder trees expanded as I would like them  to  be?

Comment: I would track this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73023588/visual-studio-2022-prevent-collapsing-folders-in-solution-explorer-2/73037410

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Visual Studio 2022: prevent collapsing folders in solution explorer (2)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73023588/visual-studio-2022-prevent-collapsing-folders-in-solution-explorer-2) Version 17.5 should have fix this.  See linked post.

Answer (score 0):

This problem was fixed in v17 of Visual Studio 2022